# Possible to add attribute to existing tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am curious if it is possible using javascript to take an existing html statement like

```
<input id="name">
```

and transform it to

```
<input id="name" asdf="fdsa">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes , try this:

```
document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("user-attr","Hello")
```

Pure Vanilla Javascript!

Comment: setAttribute("event.stopPropagation()")

The above syntax is not working.. what's the solution to this..??

Answer (score 2):

For storing data in an element you may also use [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.dataset).

```
document.getElementById("name").dataset.someDataAttr = 'mydata';
```

This will result in an attribute with name "data-some-data-attr".

Answer (score 1):

First, get the dom element:

```
var element = document.getElementById("name");
```

Then, set the attribute

```
element.setAttribute("asdf", "fdsa");
```

If you are using jQuery

```
$("#name").addr("asdf", "fdsa");
```

Comment: If it is a custom attribute it is good to prepend it with "user-"

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using jquery also

```
$('#name').attr('asdf','fdsa');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById('name').setAttribute('asdf','fdsa');
```

jQuery:

```
$("#name").attr("asdf","fdsa");
```